# HDMI KVM for Keyboards with Integrated Smart Card Reader

Tags: usb, hdmi, kvm, smartcards

This is my first question in this website. I have a Lenovo PC with integrated smart card reader keyboard (single USB cable), and a MacBook Pro. I would like to switch between the two via an HDMI KVM and this USB keyboard. The mouse is also USB.

Any recommendations?

Thank you!

Comment: Currently, I have a KVM that fails to recognize the keyboard and its integrated smart card reader.

Comment: Where do you live, i found one which claims to have keyboard, mouse screen and auto support but its one of those generic ones. so i can only find it in the netherlands.

Comment: Does it work with keyboards that come with integrated smart card reader?

Comment: I will probably ship it to where I live

Comment: I'm not sure gona read some revieuws about it. how many usb ports do you have avalible?

Comment: I have 2 on my Macbook Pro and 3 on my Lenovo PC.

Comment: do you have a minitor hooked up to the kvm switch

Comment: Yes, an HDMI monitor, USB keyboard, USB mouse. The KVM should not need drivers to be installed manually.

Comment: okey :/ what is your bugged i found some having a "all use port" but it sure is pricy

Comment: What does "all use port" mean?

Comment: As long the price is not exaggerated it is fine

Comment: what is see is that most pages say a Keyboard an mouse port. maybe they have fixed usb cabeling. I'm not very familiar with KVM's so that maybe bs.

Comment: The KVM must 100% support the keyboard integrated smart card reader running on a single USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

The [Aten 4-Port USB Peripheral Sharing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B1SENTE) Device should work with your keyboard and mouse also i has a 9 usb port version. It has a lot of wires and its messy but should work with your setup
This doesn't have Hdmi so if your old KVM still works i would add that to the mix it has a wired button which is not the best but could do

also its recommende to stick it down to you pc.

Its small and not very expensive i think this should fit your needs/comes closest to fitting your needs. it sells for about 50 Dollars at amazone.com and added a link for you.

This is a usb 2.0 KVM so make sure your keyboard and mouse can run over that type.

**Edit**: I found the HDMI version of this product with 2 usb ports. the link you can find [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045T0JVC).

Here are the instructions that should fix the problems with is. I hope this helps you.

I was looking for something to allow me to have less clutter on my desk for gaming. I wanted a single mouse and keyboard for both my pc and consoles when I game. I did not want to have to unplug and replug my mouse and keyboard when switching between the two. I did a week of research trying to find the perfect KVM switch for a price that I can justify (I really didn't want to spend $300+). One issue I read about was that with the cheaper ones, they were not compatible with gaming mice and keyboards, that if you use them you would lose functionality or they just won't work. With this KVM I was able to use my Corsair Vengeance K70 keyboard and M65 mouse just fine after some tweaking.

When I first plugged everything in, both mouse and keyboard did not work. What I had to do was plug my mouse and keyboard directly into my computer. Make sure the KVM was completely unplugged. While holding the port selector button I plugged in one of the purple USB plugs into my computer to enter firmware update mode (this is indicated by both port LEDs on the KVM blinking in unison). Visit the Aten's website and specifically look up the CS692 and download the latest firmware update. Run the program and update the KVM (if it fails make sure the kvm is still in update mode, if not reenter it). Now unplug the KVM and your mouse and keyboard from the computer. Plug the mouse and keyboard into the KVM and a set of the USB cords coming from the KVM into the computer. Make sure the KVM was selected to the correct port. I had to put my keyboard into BIOS mode. Press [Scroll Lock]>[Scroll Lock]>[m]>[Enter] to get the mouse to register. Press [Scroll Lock]>[Scroll Lock]>[n]>[Enter] to get the keyboard to work in non-bios mode. After that everything has been working great and I really enjoy the ease of my new setup.

Now for anyone who wants to use this with the XIM4, it gets kinda finicky. Make sure the black USB is plugged into Port 1, and the purple into Port 2. Have the KVM switched to the XIM4 prior to turning on the console, or switch it over and unplug and replug the XIMs USB to the console to reset it or your mouse will never mount to the XIM. Also with this specific keyboard I had to use it in BIOS mode because the XIM doesn't fully support it, not anything to do with the KVM.

I'm not sure how compatible this KVM will be with future gaming mice and keyboards but when I was looking at Aten's site, it appears they are releasing firmware updates once a year to ensure compatibility with newer devices. I will update this review if my KVM starts to malfunction or if I discover something wrong with it.

So far this was a great purchase and I couldn't be happier. Did exactly what I wanted. I would highly recommend this KVM for those who need compatibility with gaming peripherals.

Please note that I only tested the keyboard and mouse functionality. I didn't bother with the audio, or HDMI because I did not need it for what I was doing.

Comment: Thx but it is not HDMI KVM. Plus I am not sure if it supports the integrated smart card reader keyboards?

Comment: Found a fix for the hdmi version have fun. this was a revieuw from a user sorry :/

Comment: The CS692 is exactly what I have right now. Let me update the firmware and try again. I will get back to you on Sunday.

Comment: Okey, good luck with you KVM

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried upgrading the CS692 firmware with no luck. What does putting the keyboard in BIOS mode mean?

Comment: Its a compatibility mode for older bios system that only support ps2